# How to determine if Express app's connection to MongoDB is really open?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on an Angular 7 app with MongoDB, Node and Express.  If I start my Express app (using npm start command) before connecting to MongoDB (with mongod command), the Express app first throws an error because it's unable to establish connection with MongoDB.  Once MongoDB is up and running, the Express app informs me that MongoDB is now connected at port 27017.  However, any http post requests I execute through my Angular app cause Express to return a 200 status code (which tells me everything is ok), but MongoDB fails to create a document as a result of the http post request.  How do I make sure that MongoDB is not only connected but that the connection can successfully create the new document when I execute the post http request?  I read somewhere that MongoDB's ability to save/create a document requires it to have an open connection.  In that regard, what's the difference between having an open connection and MongoDB being connected at port 27017?

Here's the code I use in my Express app.js file to connect to MongoDB:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

var mongoose_uri = process.env.MONGOOSE_URI || "mongodb://abc:abc123@localhost:27017/databank?authSource=admin";
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect(mongoose_uri);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB connected at port 27017');
});

//Not sure if the mongoose.connection.once is necessary to have, considering I already have mongoose.connection.on above.

mongoose.connection.once('open', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB connection now open');
})
//MongoDB connection error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err)=>{
  console.log(err);
})
```

Here's the npm log, showing the connection error at first, followed by successful connection, followed by several Post requests with status code 200, yet nothing got saved to the MongoDB collection.

```
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
API Gateway listening at  http://localhost:8085/api
Web Server listening at  http://localhost:8085/
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017' }
MongoDB connected at port 27017
POST /api/contactus 200 335.509 ms - 18
POST /api/contactus 200 9.082 ms - 18
POST /api/contactus 200 3.916 ms - 18
POST /api/contactus 200 6.268 ms - 18
POST /api/contactus 200 61.876 ms - 18
```

Of course, this problem was resolved when I restarted my express app after an active mongoDB session, but I won't always have the luxury of inspecting logs and the app's ability to create documents when in production.  Appreciate some guidance.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @mehta-rohan: Windows

Comment: check if your MongoDB service is up and running? Also are you able to run mongo db from CLI?

Comment: MongoDB up and running already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect to mongo first, then initialize express.

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB connected at port 27017');
  app = express();
});
//once open event is not necessary
```

After that, you can consider writing init functions that all return promises. Like that you can chain it and all is clear. Here is an example where rabbit, then mongo, then express is inited.

```
initRabbit()
    .then(initMongo)
    .then(initExpress)
    .catch(e => {
        error({error:"boot", cause: e})
        process.exit(-1)
    })

const initMongo = () => new Promise(resolve => mongoose.connection.on('connected', resolve))
```

Comment: Thanks.  But shouldn't we put ```app=express();``` out of the ```mongoose.connection.on``` section?  Also, how does initializing express after the mongodb connection make the app behave differently?  I don't have a good understanding on that.  Any documentation you could point me to would be very helpful too.

Comment: Nope, it's the only place where you have a mongodb connection, and it's a prerequisite for your express services. Mongo docs speak about mongo, and express speak about express, it's your job to make them work together.

Comment: So is ```mongoose.connection.on``` an event listener for mongoDB (ie, it does something each time we connect to mongoDB)?  And that's why we should initialize express within the ```mongoose.connection.on``` section so that each time we connect to mongoDB, the event listener (mongoose.connection.on) knows to re-initialize express?  Would it also make sense to add the ```server: {auto_reconnect: true}``` option to the initial ```mongoose.connect(uri)``` command and ```mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', ()=>{app = express();})``` for the reconnected scenario?

Comment: Yes it make sense since you will call connect only one for mongo and then one for express. Later, if you have troubles, you will manage that specific trouble when it comes. Please consider give a point to answer that helped you ;)

Comment: My express app crashes if I place ```var app = express()``` within the ```mongoDB.connection.on``` section because the code has ```app.set``` and ```app.use``` statements below the ```mongoDB.connection.on``` section and the error reads "app is not defined".  How to resolve this issue now?

Comment: You may put all code about express initialization inside the mongo.on listener. Take a look at the end of my answer: initMongo is a function that return a promise which resolves when mongo is connected (so it resolve in the connection.on listener)

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a minimal example of what should be "initMongo" function.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you're saying, are you suggesting I include the rest of the code in my app.js file (all the app.use and app.set statements, including the express custom and default error handlers, and the ```module.exports = app``` statement at the end of the app.js file) within the mongoose.connection.on event?  If yes, then I tried that but my app still crashes.  If that's not what you meant, I think you've lost me with your last comment.

Comment: any guidance on how to resolve the fact that my app crashes when I place all my middleware and routs inside the mongoose.connection.on section?  It's crashing because the www.js file in the myapp/bin directory (new default express set up) tries to access ```var app``` which initializes express in myapp/app.js and is now placed inside the mongoose.connection.on section.

Comment: Ok please share a repo and I will take a look.

Comment: I was thinking about a repo with package.json and so on, everything needed to run it.

Comment: https://github.com/slimee/draft_ex/tree/master/myapp consider this as a better draft.

Comment: Thanks.  So then the startup script would be index.js?  And that will execute the other three?  So should I be stating all my dependencies (example, winston, mongoose, express, createError, cors, cookieParser, bodyParser, etc) in index.js or in the app.js/mongo.js/server.js?  Just by itself, executinig index.js throws the following error: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier``` for ```import mongo from "./mongo" ```.  Sorry for these naïve questions - I'm very much a newbie.

Comment: Write and make files as you feel it better. Do not do things because someone tell you to, but because you decided and you know why. No, index.js or foo.js, it's all as you want. What is needed is just to be clear about who does what. I've created these files just to be clear for you. One file may have a role, and only one. The role may be large or very thin, as you want. The harder is to know what is a role for you. To use import or export, you need a tool like babel. You can replace them by require and module.export. For me, I always want simplicity and I decide things for that when I code.